# Introducing surrogate key in may-to-many table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have 3 table:

`brand: brand_id(pk), name`

`product: product_id(pk), name`

`brand_product: brand_product_id(pk), brand_id, product_id`

And I have a report table, at the moment it looks like this:

`product_report: product_report_id(pk), quantity, brand_id, product_id`

My question is, what are the pros and cons of having the `brand_product_id` column instead of `brand_id`, `product_id`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that brand_product_id is *redundant*.

Yes, every table row *must* be uniquely identifiable.
Nobody *ever* said that had to be accomplished with a *single* field.

Logically, this is a "Weak Entity".  No record can exist in this table without corresponding entries in the other two tables.
It is highly *unlikely* that you would ever want to query this table *without* reference to one [or both] of the other two tables, i.e. you would always want to query it for a brand or a product.   Therefore, the [unique] combination of brand_id and product_id is sufficient for a Primary Key.

I would suggest that your *biggest* decision (if it's a decision at all) is whether to have the Primary Key on (brand_id, product_id) with an index on (product_id, brand_id) for the "reverse" look-ups, or the other way around.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the pros are:

- when using queries, you can select a specific row inside brand_product, by only using brand_product_id.
- if you want another table, connected to the brand_product table, you can specify the rows by just using the brand_product_id rather than the combination of brand_id and product_id (though, it's rare to connect a third table to a junction table like brand_product, but not impossible. I did it in my previous project)

cons:

- you can have a row with the same brand_id and product_id combination multiple times (but you can solve this by creating a unique index on the product_id and brand_id columns).

So it's not a bad idea to have a brand_product_id.

Answer (score 0):

For a many-to-many table of this sort, you can go either way. However, I would make the choice depending on if there were further relationships to the brand_product table. If there were, I'd prefer to have what you have here, brand_product_id, so that this is used as the foreign key in all those other tables instead of having to promulgate two more columns down.

However, if there are no other relationships. I'd simply go with the primary key being the two columns brand_id and product_id. The principal reason is, you will have to put a unique constraint on these columns since they are the natural key to the table. This means you're maintaining two indexes instead of just one. Without the downstream tables, that's additional overhead that I don't have to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at some criteria for a good candidate key:

```
* Unique
* Stable
* Simple
* Irreducible
* Familiar
```

Ideal all properties should be satisfied, but often one has to sacrifice one of these. In your particular case, one could argue that:

```
* (brand_id, product_id) is too complex (personally I don't think so)
* (brand_product_id) is probably a surrogate key and therefor not familiar.
```

Regardless of which way you go, you should always declare all candidate keys. Either:

```
PRIMARY KEY (brand_product_id)
UNIQUE (brand_id, product_id)
```

or:

```
PRIMARY KEY (brand_id, product_id)
```

Personally, I would go with the latter in this case, but there is no absolute truth out there. Weigh advantages vs disadvantages with both alternatives and remember why you choose one over the other.